# How does Fe2+ become Fe in sacrificial protection?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrons

I've searched low and high on the internet, but nothing to help me.

I know that zinc is oxidised in preference to iron, and that it "donates" those two electrons to iron.
$$\ce{Zn -> Zn^2+ + 2e-}$$

But how does iron make use of those two electrons to revert back to iron when it turns into iron oxide, like so:

$$\ce{Fe^2+ + 2e- -> Fe}$$

Doesn't the $\ce{Fe^2+}$ in the $\ce{Fe2O3}$ need to be dissolved in water? How can it be affected by $\ce{2e-}$ travelling along? Maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the point that you're missing is that $\ce{Fe2O3}$ is never formed when there is $\ce{Zn}$ in the system. When the metal gets oxidized, the electrons come from the $\ce{Zn}$, not from the $\ce{Fe}$. This is true even if the physical location of the oxidation is on the iron, since the $\ce{Fe}$ and $\ce{Zn}$ are connected and conductive, so all of the electrons on both are shared.

Comment: So wait. Does this mean that the oxygen gets its electrons (which came from Zinc ions) but the zinc does not get attached to it to form zinc oxide? I am talking about when the physical location of the oxidation is on the iron.

Comment: Exactly. The oxide formation and the oxidation are actually separate reactions. After the zinc is oxidized to $\ce{Zn^{2+}}$, it can dissolve in water if there is enough present, or it can react with water to give zinc hydroxide ($\ce{Zn(OH)2}$) or zinc oxde ($\ce{ZnO})$. But these oxygen atoms need not be the same ones that were reduced. Salty water greatly increases the rate of reaction because it conducts charge easily between the site of reduction (Fe metal) and oxidation (Zn metal) to offset the electron movement just as in an electrochemical cell.

Comment: But what happens to the reduced oxygen atoms? Isn't it necessary for an ion to be part of a compound or be dissolved in order to exist as an ion? Fundamentally I guess it's possible, but the forces of attraction between negative and positive charges in the world would not allow the ion to.

Comment: The sacrificial Zn only works if the Fe and Zn are also connected by water (preferably salty). So when the oxygen gets reduced, it picks up protons to form water. That means hydroxide is formed somewhere. Through proton transfers in the water, the negative charge is "conducted" to the location of the zinc ion and the hydroxide is formed there, so the negative and positive charges are united.

Comment: Aluminum is used to protect steel in sea water; A complex "calcareous" deposit is built up on the steel which reduces the amount of sacrificial aluminum needed for protection.

Comment: @Andrew You're such a legend, bud. I am painfully and slowly getting it now. Much of my misconception is cleared by "The oxide formation and the oxidation are actually separate reactions." However what exactly do you mean by oxygen picks up protons to form WATER?

Comment: If you keep adding electrons to $\ce{O2}$, you eventually get two $\ce{O^{2-}}$. Add protons to get $\ce{H2O}$.

Comment: @Andrew I just remembered that $\ce{H^+}$ ion is basically a proton. Sometimes you forget this sort of stuff too hehe. So basically the reduced oxygen atoms at the iron surface bump into oxidised hydrogen atoms (protons) somewhere and form water. Is that correct?